# Need to get parameters alone from query as arraylist return parameter

Tags: java, regex

I have written program  which will take Query as input and to get parameters alone as arraylist return (used Regex patern Split) (OUTPUT)
but i am getting with () also if we added like its also coming.

**Input**

```
SELECT * FROM some_table 
WHERE some_column1 = ‘%(some_parameter_1)%’ and 
      some_column2=’%(some_parameter_2)%’ and 
      some_column3=’%(some_parameter_3)%’;`
```

**Output**

An array list containing the following elements in it:

```
some_parameter_1
some_parameter_2
some_parameter_3
```

---

```
String patternString = "%";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

String[] split = pattern.split(query);

System.out.println("split.length = " + split.length);

for(String element : split){
    System.out.println("element = " + element);
    a1.add(element);
}

int n = a1.size();
for(int j =1;j <= n; j=j+2){
    params.add(a1.get(j));
}
System.out.println("\n List of Parameters  "+params);
/* for(int j =1;j <= 7; j=+1)
System.out.println(a1.get(j)); */
    return params;
}
```

How to use match.result in regex? thats not getting effect it seems... or any other way to solve It.

I need the parameter alone enclosed in %(some-param1)% as a arraylist return.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern, as well as your approach, will not lead you to your solution because using split,you will split on the pattern. Instead you want to match the pattern and extract the matched pattern.

For this, we can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` class provided in java. The pattern which I have used `(%\\()(.*?)(\\)%)`. Note `\\` has been added for escaping

It has three section

1)  `(%\\()` Search for a string starting with `%(`

2) `(.*?)` All the characters after the first one matched

3) `(\\)%)` Match till you find `)%` character.

Below is the sample working code for your example. Because we want to extract what is between `%(...)%` which is the second part, I have used `group(2)`.

So `matcher.group(1)` will match `%(`, `matcher.group(2)` will match `some_parameter_1` and `matcher.group(3)` will match `)%`. Doing it in a loop will parse the whole string and give all three parameters in ArrayList

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column1 = ‘%(some_parameter_1)%’ and some_column2=’%(some_parameter_2)%’ "
            + "and some_column3=’%(some_parameter_3)%’;";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(%\\()(.*?)(\\)%)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    List<String> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        parameterList.add(matcher.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println(parameterList);
}
```